Using std::mt19937 and std::uniform_int_distribution to generate random numbers in range causes application to crash with error code (0xc000007b)
I have a simple cpp program that generates random number between given range [code below]
Code reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-random-number-in-range-in-cpp/
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    const int range_from  = 1;
    const int range_to    = 4;
    std::random_device                  rand_dev;
    std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(range_from, range_to);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        std::cout << distr(generator) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

I compile the program as such:

g++ gen_random.cpp

After this, when i execute the program, the application crashes with error code:  (0xc000007b)
g++ version used ->

g++ (GCC) 14.2.0

Error observed [below image]:


You are experiencing the DLL hell. std::mt19937 the title is unlikely a reason.

Works here. -- You would have probably seen the same issue if you had a simple "Hello World" program.  I agree that the std::mt19947 has nothing to do with the issue, and it more than likely is your installation of the compiler and the compiler's libraries / required DLL's.

Run this under debugger to get detailed information why this crashed. Probably some implicitly loaded dll was not located.

Yes this is a dll problem and nothing to do with the code: https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc000007b) It could be that one of the required dlls were found in a folder of your PATH environment variable however its not the correct 32 / 64 bit.

Yes, I agree there was some issue with my compiler [some DLL was missing / not located]. Removed the current compiler files and got the gcc/g++ from https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/ [using https://www.msys2.org/]. Now my program works fine. Thanks to all for the pointing out the probable issue !

I do recommend using msys2 because its usually the most current MinGW version and on top of that it has by far the best package management. It any case you still have to be careful on what folders are in your PATH environment variable because it's easy to have some software (which may not even be compiler related) install an incompatible version of the MinGW runtime dlls that conflict with your current version of your compiler.
